# VB.NET Collection Array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, email

Situation:

I have 3 "types" of e-mail recipients:

```
1st: Users
2nd: Users who are in a special group
3rd: Users who are in a special department
```

To every type belongs a different mail, that's why I split them up.
I'm using for this VisualBasic .NET and the `System.Net.Mail` Class.

Following Code:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Sub Main()
    Dim recipients(3) As MailAddressCollection
    recipients(1).Add("my@email.com")
    Debug.Print(recipients(1).ToString)
End Sub
```

I can't do this though. The debug crashes at the `Add` Line. I can not add it if the array isn't initalized. Visual Studio suggests to use the "new" Keyword, which works neither because I can't initialize arrays with new.

What am I missing? I feel so stupid right now.

Comment: `I'm using for this VisualBasic 6` - you aren't. If this code is even close to compiling, you are using Visual Basic .NET.

Comment: What is MailAddressCollection? and where is code for MailAddressCollection?

Comment: Note that you mean `recipients(2)` not `recipients(3)`. The latter contains 4 elements - numbered 0-3. (ie the array indexing is zero-based)

Comment: @AshReva: MailAddressCollection is a framework class in the namespace imported in the code. See MSDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an array, initialize each member of the array, use members that have been initialized.

```
Dim recipients(2) As MailAddressCollection
recipients(0) = New MailAddressCollection
recipients(1) = New MailAddressCollection
recipients(2) = New MailAddressCollection

recipients(0).Add("my@email.com")
```